# What's the framework mechanism behind dependency properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have been reading about dependency properties in several books but all have one thing in common, they just tell us how they are implemented( using `static readonly DependencyProperty` etc.) but does not tell the exact way they work from inside.

I mean they are implemented as static but still applies to all objects.
Second point of confusion is attached properties.

Is there any tutorial available that can explain all these concepts in an easy way?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My mental model of how dependency properties work:

Any `DependencyObject` class implements two special properties.  One, a static property of the class, is a dictionary of `DependencyProperty` objects.  Every instance of the class can look inside that dictionary to find metainformation about each `DependencyProperty` - the property's name, its type, any callbacks that have to be called when it's get and set, how it participates in property inheritance, and so on.  When you register a dependency property, you're adding an entry to this dictionary.

The other property is an instance property:  it's a dictionary, keyed by `DependencyProperty`, that contains the local *value* of each `DependencyProperty`, if it has been set.

The `SetValue` and `GetValue` methods that you implement in the setter and getter of the CLR property are basically lazy evaluation on steroids.  Instead of storing and retrieving the value of the property in a backing field, they store and retrieve the value of the property in the value dictionary.

The magic of dependency properties is in what `GetValue` and `SetValue` actually do.

`GetValue` looks up the value for the property in the object's value dictionary.  If it doesn't find it, it calls `GetValue` on the parent element, to get what the parent element thinks the value is.  For instance, when you create a `TextBox` in a `Window`, anything that looks at the `TextBox`'s `FontFamily` is actually calling `GetValue`.  Unless you've explicitly set the font, there's no entry in its dictionary for that property.  So `GetValue` asks the parent element for the value.  The parent element may or may not have `FontFamily` set; if not, *its* call to `GetValue` to returns the value from *its* parent.  And so on, until the `Window` object is reached and the actual `FontFamily` value is found.

If you set `FontFamily` on the `TextBox`, `SetValue` stores the value in the value dictionary.  The next time anything needs to get the value of the `FontFamily` for that `TextBox`, `GetValue` finds the value in the dictionary and returns it, so it doesn't need to ask the parent element.

If you set `FontFamily` on the `Window`, `SetValue` not only updates the value in `Window`'s value dictionary, it fires off a property-change event that everything dependent on the property hears.  (That's why they're called dependency properties, remember.)  And if the thing depending on the property is itself a dependency property, it fires off its own property-change events.  This is how it is that changing the `FontFamily` on the `Window` changes the font for every control in the window and also prompts WPF to re-render the controls that have changed.

Attached properties work using the same kind of approach.  Any object that can have attached properties has a dictionary that the attached properties' values are stored in.  When you set `Grid.Column` on a `CheckBox` in XAML, you're just adding an entry to that `CheckBox`'s dictionary.  When the `Grid` needs to know what column the `CheckBox` is in, it looks the value up from that dictionary.  When you set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` to `True` on an object, that object's dictionary will contain a new property - a dictionary that contains widths/heights for each `SharedSizeKey`.

I should emphasize that this is my mental model.  I haven't sat down with Reflector and looked at the *actual* implementation of `Register`, `GetValue`, and `SetValue` to figure out how they actually work.  I may be wrong about the details.  But it's a model that accurately predicts how this stuff behaves, so it's good enough.

The concept of storing property values in dictionaries is pretty weird to C# programmers.  It's old hat to Python programmers, though.  In Python, all class properties - all objects, in fact - are stored in dictionaries, and so you can get to their value either through property accessors or just by looking them up.  Dependency properties and attached properties are just another way in which .NET, having stolen everything Java had that was worth stealing, is now plundering Python.  (Or from wherever Python plundered them from.)  Learning Python has made me a much better C# programmer; I recommend it to any C# developer who hasn't done it yet.

Comment: Robert, so much thanks for that wonderful explaination.I could now imagine how they work.I could not understand Attached properties properly.Here is what I understood :The checkbox has a Dictionary  keyed by a static property.That dictionary can have keyed values for all the properties that the CheckBox has.But it can also contain other values keyed by the static properties (Grid.Column) of other objects(Grid).When the Grid wants to know about it's location it looks for an entry keyed by Grid.Column and Grid.Row and uses it.So we can add an entry for Grid.Column even when it not inside a Grid.

Comment: It sounds right to me, though "That dictionary can have keyed values for all the properties that the CheckBox has" should say "dependency properties."  Also I should point out that when I wrote the above post I was under the misapprehension that attached properties were a mechanism like dependency properties; in fact attached properties *are* dependency properties.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a tutorial on dependency properties http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html that explains a little bit about how they work.

The short explanation of why the DependencyProperty object is in a static field is that it represents the *description* of the property, not the value of the property.  Each DependencyObject has a mapping from DependencyProperty objects to their values.

This is also how attached properties work.  Because each DependencyObject is storing a mapping from any DependencyProperty to a value, any type can create a new DependencyProperty and set it on any existing DependencyObject.

Answer (score 2):

just see this post by joshsmith it has some additional informatin in it

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/22/overview-of-dependency-properties-in-wpf/

Comment: Yes, I already visited it and it is helpful, still i am waiting for others to help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can see below a very basic example of `dependency property` that creates a `custom control text box` in which space will be not allowed means user can not type space into text box.

1) Create a class with the name of `ValidatedTextBox` and write the following code in this class file:

```
public class ValidatedTextBox : TextBox  
{  
    public ValidatedTextBox()  
    {
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpaceAllowedProperty =  
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsSpaceAllowed", typeof(bool), typeof(ValidatedTextBox));  

    public bool IsSpaceAllowed
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IsSpaceAllowedProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(IsSpaceAllowedProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        if (!IsSpaceAllowed && (e.Key == Key.Space))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Now use the above control into your `.XAML` file

a) Add namespace of custom control text box like below:

```
xmlns:CustomControls="clr-namespace: ValidatedTextBox;assembly= ValidatedTextBox "
```

b) Now, use custom control text box like below:

```
<CustomControls:ValidatedTextBox IsSpaceAllowed="False" x:Name="MyTextBox" />
```

It will create a custom control text box that will not allow space. So, Basically Dependency property allows to add feature, extend feature of any control.